# Error while sending Authorization header using jquery to a non native server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

I am sending a string along with the `Authorization` header while calling a self made API service. On the server end, I receive those info using PHP's `apache_request_headers()` method to split out all header info and to get the string sent via `Authorization` for my further usage.
Ajax Call I make:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://x.x.x.x/speaker/api/sounds",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        },
        success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
});
```

**Note:** I can receive the sent value of `Authorization` header if I make the call from a client script which runs inside same domain of the API provider script. Such as - all works fine if the API consumer script and API provider stays in my localhast or under same domain/ip of my remote server.

**Problem:** Does not work only if I run the client script from a location other than the API provider's location. It returns with a `Invalid HTTP status code 404` error observed in browser's (Chrome) console.

I have updated the .htaccess file to:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

So, there is no more **Allowing Origin issue**, its now **Sending/Getting custom header information on PHP end set by jQuery** issue.

Comment: **UPDATE:** A CURL from anywhere to my server even works fine ```curl http://x.x.x.x/speaker/api/sounds -H 'Authorization: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'```  
Seems a certificate issue while using ```OPTIONS``` from inside any unauthorised location via JS.

Answer (score 3):

you can add this into your .htaccess

> RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

Comment: No luck, @tareq-jobayere
Sending and receiving value of Authorization is not the blockage issue. Its working but not with different location.  
Authorization is not being received properly only when its going from an different origin.

Comment: How come tools like Advanced REST client sends these headers and being processed by server end perfectly! But for example - making a call from localserver to a remote server is creating the pain.